# Solving equation with harmonic number and find a parameter

Tags: equation-solving

I need to solve this equation and find k subsequent c. Plz help me
[image]

I try to solve it but HarmonicNumber is divergent. So I can’t find solution. In this equation d=0 [image]and r=0.25. I need find k in term of B.

Comment: Suggesting to close it because it is not a Mathematica question.

Comment: Thanks. Why I can’t find this with mathematica? I need k param of this equation and use it to another equation and plot c=B*k^2. I need plot c in terms of B. I have B in two equation.

Comment: Do any of the parameters have known numeric values? Any known constraints? Real? Nonnegative? Positive? Bounded?

Comment: Maybe it’s better  replace k in terms of B and c in first equation and plot c in terms B. I know r and d values.

Comment: Yes I know r and d. both of them are integer and positive. r is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Edit the question to include the known values and the constraint.

Comment: I do it. Is it enough?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need solve this equation and find k in terms of B and another parameters are number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

d = 10;
r = 1/4;
```

Use a finite sum and check for convergence

```
eqn[nmax_] :=
  Sum[Exp[-B k^2 (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d]) //
       FunctionExpand], {n, 1, nmax}] == (1 - r) E^(k^2)/r - 1 //
   Simplify;

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eqn[85], eqn[90]},
  {B, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 2},
  ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {B, k}),
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 4]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The plot from the paper indicates that it is for `d = 0` rather than `d == 10`. However, there is still disagreement between the plots. Without knowing more about how the paper generated its plot, I cannot explain the difference.

```
Clear[d, r]

eqn[d_Integer?NonNegative, r_, nmax_Integer?Positive] :=
  Sum[Exp[-c (HarmonicNumber[n + d] - HarmonicNumber[d])],
    {n, 1, nmax}] == ((1 - r) E^(c/B) - 1)/r;

rValues = {1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 9/10};

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 ContourPlot[
  Evaluate@
   Table[eqn[0, r, 100], {r, rValues}],
  {B, 1/20, 1}, {c, 0, 2.25},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {B, c}),
  RotateLabel -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 4,
  WorkingPrecision -> 50,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[N@rValues,
     LegendLabel -> "r ="],
    {.1, .6}],
  GridLines -> {None, {2}},
  GridLinesStyle ->
   Directive[Gray, AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashed]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob . But this isn’t same with my paper plot.

Comment: Is the paper plot also `k` vs `B` or is it `c` vs `B*k^2`? In any event, if you know what the plot is supposed to look like, edit your question to include a scan of the plot. It is easier to help you if you help us.

Comment: In the paper plot c vs B*k^2. I think if I replace k^2 with (c/B),can find the right plot.

Comment: I add the paper plot. Its for 4 values of r. I plot your cod and replace k^2 for 4 values of r. But it’s not matching with this plot. Thanks for your time. 

Comment: Yes. My plot same with yours. But it’s not true. c should be asymptotic line d=1. Can i find k in this equation in mathematica?